# How to generate Sqoop command from Sqoop options?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera, sqoop

I want to generate Sqoop commands to import RDBMS tables from Mysql. I have the sqoop commands stored DB and later the Oozie workflows are created with this command. I write the Sqoop commands manually now.

Is there a way i could create an object of SqoopOptions , set the values and generate sqoop queries out of the object ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could.  You'll want to call/extend the classes [here](https://github.com/apache/sqoop/tree/trunk/src/java/org/apache/sqoop/tool).